# I have done a k-nn model in python, how can I save it to tflite?

Tags: python, tensorflow

There is a way to convert a k-near neighbors model to tflite? as I know '.pb doesn't save the dataset values, only stores the graph and variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A TensorFlow Lite model doesn't save the dataset values. It is cleaner way of saving TensorFlow graphs.

For a KNN, you need to create this algorithm in TF and then use `tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_session_graph()` to specify the input and output tensors for the KNN.

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_session_graph( inputs, outputs )
buffer = converter.convert()
open( "model.tflite", 'wb' ).write(buffer)
```

Where `inputs` could be the placeholder tensors for the model and `outputs` could be the tensors which provide the class label for the predicted class.

**Tip:**

KNN is a simple algorithm, which I think could be easily implemented in any programming language. I suggest you create an algorithm in the native language. You will have more control flow over the working of it..